# Streamlit Unhashable TypeError when i use st.cache

Tags: huggingface-transformers, streamlit

when i use the st.cache decorator to cash hugging-face transformer model i get

> **Unhashable TypeError**

this is the code

```
from transformers import pipeline 
import streamlit as st 
from io import StringIO

@st.cache(hash_funcs={StringIO: StringIO.getvalue})
def model() :
    return pipeline("sentiment-analysis", model='akhooli/xlm-r-large-arabic-sent')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This worked for me:

```
from transformers import pipeline 
import tokenizers
import streamlit as st 
import copy


@st.cache(hash_funcs={tokenizers.Tokenizer: lambda _: None, tokenizers.AddedToken: lambda _: None})
def get_model() :
    return pipeline("sentiment-analysis", model='akhooli/xlm-r-large-arabic-sent')

input = st.text_input('Text')
bt = st.button("Get Sentiment Analysis")

if bt and input:
    model = copy.deepcopy(get_model())
    st.write(model(input))
```

**Note 1**:
calling the pipeline with input `model(input)` changes the model and we shouldn't change a cached value so we need to copy the model and run it on the copy.

**Note 2**:
First run will load the model using the `get_model` function next run will use the chace.

**Note 3**:
You can read more about Advanced caching in stremlit in thier [documentation](https://docs.streamlit.io/library/advanced-features/caching#example-2-turn-off-hashing-for-a-specific-type).

Output examples:

[image: 1]

[image: 2]

Comment: this worked too i tried allow_output_mutation = True

and it worked too

Answer (score 3):

after searching in issues section in streamlit repo

i found that hashing argument is not required , just need to pass this argument

> allow_output_mutation = True